# iOS change height constraint UITableViewCell from nested UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have very specific task:

1. I have main tableview
2. Each cell in this tableview has nested tableview
3. When on nested tableview occurs willDisplayCell I need change height constraint on main table cell (nested tableview owner)

The main problem is that main tableview cell constraints don't updating. (until after begin scroll).

I tried next variants:

1. call setNeedLayout, layoutIfNeed, setNeedDisplay, setUpdateConstraints in different variations
2. using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...})

I think I am missing something.
I thank all in advance. And waiting for your proposal.

Comment: And what is interesting, when i force setNeedLayout, layoutIfNeed on main tableview cell with new height constraint, layoutsubviews it is triggered, but cell height  stay the same

Comment: When an element in a cell changes the height of the cell, you need to inform the table view so it can re-calculate the cell heights. If you put together a [mre] we can show you how to do it.

Comment: @DonMag This isn't true for auto sizing cells.

Comment: @förschter - the OP never followed up on this, but it's pretty clear he is trying to get the cells to auto-size based on the dynamic height of the nested tableView. The problem is that the nested tableView height is not determined until ***after*** the "outer" table view has laid out **its** cells. That's why the cell needs to inform the table view that its content height has changed and needs to be updated.